# Chrome not showing bold at all

Tags: html, css

basically I used that famous google font called "Thasadith" I used only the "bold" version and its just showing the normal version , I rechecked , used  in html , used font weight in css and still the font is just viewed as normal..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can better help solve your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to **load** the bold font if you want to use it. If you don't, the browser doesn't know how to render the `bold` weight and defaults to the closest it has (which is the one you loaded: `normal`).

In the case of Thasadith, which is available on Google fonts, you need to add `:n,b` after the font family name in the `<link>`'s url (or in the `@import`'s url), where `n` stands for `normal` and `b` stands for `bold` (other available options being `i` - italic, `bi`, - bolditalic or specific weights - these depend on font, ranging from `100` to `900`. as well as specific weight + `i`).

Here's a working example with Thasadith:

```css
div {
  font-family: 'Thasadith';
  font-size: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Thasadith:n,i,b,bi" rel="stylesheet">

<div>Hel<i>lo</i>, <strong>Wor<i>ld!</i></strong></div>
```

In the case of Thasadith,

```
family=Thasadith:n,i,b,bi
```

is equivalent to

```
family=Thasadith:400,400i,700,700i
```

as `400` and `700` are the two available weights.

For more on how to load Google fonts, read their [getting started](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started).

Comment: "load the bold form" → "load the bold font", I presume

Comment: @WalterTross, thanks for the suggestion. FYI, I welcome edits on my posts, especially fixing typos.

Comment: thank _you_. Didn't edit because I wasn't 100% sure